# Could not Load Plugin due to Error: "Jar does not contain plugin.yml"

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to create a Spigot plugin that allows players to use a compass to track other players. While exporting and running the server, I noticed that it was giving me an error:

```
[21:57:15 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\Manhunt.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:172) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:148) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:389) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:252) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1066) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:290) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-683]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
        ... 7 more
```

I have never seen this error before and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have made sure to export the `.yml` file while in Eclipse, but it still shows me this error.

Comment: A Minecraft Plugin cannot run without a plugin.yml, as it is what defines the name, main, commands, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `plugin.yml` file is a required part of a SpigotMC plugin that defines some basic information about the plugin like its name and the version of the Spigot API that it uses. For example, [here](https://github.com/jhale1805/power-projectiles/blob/master/src/main/resources/plugin.yml)'s one for a Minecraft plugin I'm currently working on.

The error you're getting comes from that file not getting bundled into the jar. As a result, when the Spigot server tries to load your plugin, it can't find the `plugin.yml` because it's literally not present in your compiled jar.

I recommend setting up a build system like Gradle or Maven that will handle the complexities of building the jar for you independent of the IDE you use.

- [Set up a SpigotMC plugin using Maven](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-plugin-with-maven-using-intellij-idea/)
- [Set up a SpigotMC plugin using Gradle](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/build-you-spigot-plugin-with-gradle-groovy/)

I personally use Gradle, so feel free to see how I implemented it in [one of my plugins](https://github.com/jhale1805/power-projectiles). If you'd prefer Maven, there are many examples available including the popular [Multiverse-Core](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core).

Answer (score 0):

You need the plugin.yml to run your plugin. If you're using spigot or bukkit, you should make your plugin.yml inside the src folder, in there, you need to include a minimum of:

```
name: (plugin name, no spaces allowed in name)
author: (your name)
version: (your plugin version)
api-version: (use 1.14)
main: (your main class)
description: (optional description, otherwise delete this line)
```

then you can export or rebuild the jar

This is an example of what my plugin.yml looks like:

```
name: ThornsPlugin
version: 1.0
author: MOREORLESS
api-version: 1.14
main: com.MOREORLESS.plugin.plugin
description: MC Stuff
```

Learn more about Plugin.yml here: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/